# Angular $watch window.pageYOffset not updating?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my controller, I have:

```
$scope.woffset = window.pageYOffset;

 $scope.$watch("woffset", function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("hello");
    console.log(window.pageYOffset);
 }, true);
});
```

So when I scroll, I should be receiving console logs of "hello" as the pageYOffset changes. However, it doesn't do anything. But if I run window.pageYOffset in the console as I scroll down, I can see that the value is changing. Any ideas?

I've tried multiple variations of watch (with and without true, using functions instead of strings, but nothing seems to work).

(I know there is a work around with onscroll, but I'd like to learn how it would work this way) Thanks!

Edit: This doesn't seem to work either:

```
$scope.test = function () { 
    return window.pageYOffset;
}

$scope.$watch("test", function (newValue, oldValue) {
console.log("hello");
console.log(window.pageYOffset);
}, true);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you did not use scroll event?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `$scope.woffset` is being set to a normal number - it's never changing. It's like doing the following:

```
var i = 5;
var j = i;

i = 7;
// Wondering here why j isn't 7
```

There are 2 ways to solve your problem - the naive way or the more efficient way.

First:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    console.log("hello");
    console.log(window.pageYOffset);
    // any $scope variable updates
    $scope.$digest();
};
```

However, with this solution, every time you scroll this will be running like crazy. The more efficient way would be to use the above solution combined with some "debouncing" - check out this Stack Overflow question to learn about doing that [Can I debounce or throttle a watched <input> in AngularJS using _lodash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088845/can-i-debounce-or-throttle-a-watched-input-in-angularjs-using-lodash)

One problem this has is it will never un-watch scrolling, even once the controller is garbage collected. To solve this problem, also do the following:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    window.onscroll = null;
});
```

Comment: What? When do you think `$digest` will be triggered?

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned, I'd prefer not to use onscroll. Two reasons: 1. I'd like to learn how to do it with pageYOffset and $watch. But also window.onscroll seems to only be able to be called once (if you have two window.onscroll functions, only the second one will work) which will not work for my purposes.

Comment: The problem is that $watch only runs every digest cycle. For example, when you change text in an input, AngularJS internally is running a plain javascript event listener, and inside the callback calling `$scope.$digest()`. However, AngularJS doesn't automatically do it for the `onscroll` event, so you have to call `$scope.$digest()` yourself.

Comment: If you don't understand the difference between a Javascript event and an AngularJS digest cycle I recommend reading up on that - it's a very important concept.

Answer (score 1):

One good thing to verify is that your window.pageYOffset value is actually changing.  Scroll the window then execute a window.pageYOffset in the console to verify it is changing.  It could be that you are scrolling a child container and not the window so you are not seeing any change.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.element($window).on("scroll resize", function (e) {
console.log($window.pageYOffset)
});

scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
angular.element($window).unbind("scroll resize");
});
```