# Can I detect when the scope variable post event changed?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

So I want an animation in my ionic app:

```
  $scope.$watch("room.game.blackCard.text",
        function( newValue, oldValue ) {
            if(newValue === oldValue) {return false;}
            else if (oldValue == null || oldValue.length == 0 ) {return false;}
            else {
                $scope.room.game.blackCard.animate = 'animated bounceOutLeft';
                $timeout( function(){
                    $scope.room.game.blackCard.animate = 'animated bounceInRight';
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    );
```

I know it's not healthy to use watch but my problem is that I want to apply the second class when the variable has changed, is there a way to detect the post-update variable?

I noticed the 'watch is triggered on a `pre-update` variable.

If I could detect `post-update` then I would apply the `$timeout`.

**Problem**: When the div slides to the left the text changes in mid-animation then a the div comes back from the left.

**Q1**: Can I detect `post-update` variable?

**Q2**: Can I **delay** the variable update? (ex: Set the new var in the callback of `settimeout` -> `$timeout` callback)

Comment: is your `room.game.blackCard.text` a `ng-model` on an `input`/`select` i.e. updated in a form?

Comment: It's not binded in a ng-model, it changes via socket server (emits an update).

Comment: okay - you should be able to use `debounce` to delay the variable update. See this example that uses lodash debounce: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088845/can-i-debounce-or-throttle-a-watched-input-in-angularjs-using-lodash

Comment: Thank you!!! I'll try it. I did not see that post.